# Google Admob is not finding my App-ads.txt. How do I change this within a web-builder?

Tags: html, admob, txt, app-ads.txt

Google only allows me to post on their community forum for contact support. This has resulted in 0 responses over 2 weeks.

Here is the problem:

- Google Admob is not finding my app-ads.txt
- I suspect this is because the app-ads.txt is written in text on my website for the domain, but is not actually an .txt file. Website: https://herotrainer.io/app-ads.txt
- I am unable upload a file to the root directory of the web-builder I am using - Dorik. At least they have told me I cannot.
- I have control over editing header/foot code for the page and adding a html code element.

Are there any options for me to bypass this or do I need to host on another website that allows me to upload .txt file?